# Question about fluid expansion

Tags: thermodynamics

Hy,

When a hot and dense fluid suddenly expands, how much can it cool down.

Lets take for example an expansion valve from an AC, does the fluid do work when passing through the valve or does it not even need to do work in order to cool down.

What is the lowest temperature that the fluid can cool down to?

I hope I've been clear enough, thanks.

Comment: An AC might be a bad example, since it uses phase transition to transport heat.

Comment: That's ok it can use any mechanism to transport heat, I am just interested in how much a fluid cools down when expanding.